# How to create date trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

How can I create a trigger to increase a date data from my table with each next row? I had an attempt, is below the table

What I want to do is to increase date from `training_date_end` by 1 week. But I don't know how to do it, just studying. Can anyone help?

```
CREATE TABLE training 
(
    coach_id int NOT NULL,
    customer_id int NOT NULL,
    training_date_start date NULL,
    training_date_end date NULL,
    training_place_id int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT training_pk PRIMARY KEY (training_place_id)
);

create or replace trigger lucky_week
before insert or update on training
for each row
begin
    update training
       set training_date_end = :new.training_date_end + 7
     where training_date_end = :new.training_date_end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably like this:

```
create or replace trigger lucky_week
  before insert or update on training
  for each row
begin
  :new.training_date_end := :new.training_date_end + 7;
end;
```

Because, your trigger will suffer from the **mutating table** error (if you insert more than a single row), and - won't do anything in that case (because row you'd like to update doesn't exist yet).